# What different desktop environments are available?

Tags: unity, gnome, kubuntu, xubuntu, desktop-environments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What different DE's and shells are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65083/what-different-des-and-shells-are-available)

I like to play with desktop environments and I know how to get Kubuntu, Xubuntu and Gnome but I don't know how to get any others. It would be great if someone could tell me about others and how to get them and is there an easy was to manage DE's and remove them? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To install openbox desktop, use

> sudo apt-get install openbox

To install LXDE, use

> sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop

To install E17(Enlightment desktop), use

> sudo apt-get install e17

To install Cinnamon(A GNOME Shell fork), use

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:merlwiz79/cinnamon-ppa
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install cinnamon cinnamon-session cinnamon-settings

Comment: Cinnamon doesn't work without Gnome 3